# Micropython: How to use utime.mktime() without knowing the weekday/yearday?

Tags: time, micropython

I'm trying to convert an ISO time string like '2021-05-11T18:21:35Z' to an int (seconds from epoch), which mktime() does, except it seems strange to me that it requires the weekday and yearday as part of the argument. In general, it seems unlikely that you would know this, and in my situation I don't.

Obviously in python this is doable with things like datetime, but in uPython these don't exist and I haven't seen a non-external-library way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much like with regular Python, the values of `weekday` and `yearday` are ignored (they get computed from the other values and are only accepted so that you can pass `mktime` the tuple returned by e.g. `localtime`).

You can run:

```
MicroPython v1.14 on 2021-03-07; ESP module with ESP8266
Type "help()" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> res = time.mktime((2021, 5, 11, 18, 21, 35, 0, 0))
>>> res
674072495
>>> time.localtime(res)
(2021, 5, 11, 18, 21, 35, 1, 131)
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot more sense.